# Convert date to format yyyy-MM-dd+timezone

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wanna change the input date with time and time zone to this format yyyy-MM-dd+timezone

Example:
I have this input

```
Sat Oct 05 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale)
```

I want an output like this

```
2019-10-05+2:00
```

Is there a simple way to convert this?

Comment: Have you used [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) ? This is a great tool to convert dates and time

Comment: @MykWillis I closed the question when the Angular tag was present. I thought it was related to Angular. I'm re-opening it !

Comment: Well I can't re-open it, i can just vote to re-open it ... Either you guys vote too, or simply create a new question (And **DO NOT** use the Angular tag)

Comment: Someone's got a trigger-happy finger! ;-) I had an answer in the making and I voted to reopen.

Comment: @ConstantinGroß you don't say ! I'm the gate-keeper of the Angular board and trust me, there's a lot to do ... But hey, maybe that answered him !

Comment: As with most things date and time related, the "simple" way is almost certainly going to end up being (1) not so simple, and (2) wrong in some situations of time and place.

Use moment.js:

> var moment = require('moment');
> moment.parseZone(`Sat Oct 05 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200`).format("YYYY-MM-DDZ")
'2019-10-05+02:00'

Comment: `https://github.com/akshaybande81/date-conversion-javascript/wiki` use this link

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with simple `Date` functions.

```
public transform(date: Date): string {
    return `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth()+1}-${date.getDate() >= 10 ? date.getDate() : '0'+date.getDate()}${date.getTimezoneOffset()}`;
}
```

Comment: no it's not correct.. it return this `2019-10-05-120` and no `2019-10-05+2:00`

Comment: You have to handle `TimezoneOffset` convert offset to hours. It's giving wrong answer.